# Selecting whole row in Mysql database using C# and saving it as a list

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to select one specific row from my mysql database.

In SQL I'd just use

```
select * from endkunden where id = 2;
```

this works just fine, I get everything I want.

Now I want to do this in my c# code and save the data into a string list.

I tried doing it like this

```
public List<string> SelectListRow(string target, string table,string idef, int id)
    {
        string query = "SELECT " + target + " FROM " + table + " where "+ idef + " = " +id;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        if (this.OpenConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {

                list.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader[target]));
            }

            dataReader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
            return list;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Since this worked for selecting all columns in the table using

```
select compname from endkunden;
```

I assumed, that this would work with rows as well, but it doesn't. When using it like this

I use the following query:

```
select * 
from endkunden 
where id = 2
```

but now I get an error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException
>   HResult=0x80131508
>   Nachricht = Could not find specified column in results: *
>   Quelle = MySql.Data
>
> Stapelüberwachung:
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.GetOrdinal(String name)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
>   at MySQL_Tests.DBAC.SelectListRow(String target, String table, String idef, Int32 id) in C:\Users\Murf\source\repos\MySQL Tests\MySQL Tests\DBAC.cs:line 187
>   at MySQL_Tests.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Murf\source\repos\MySQL Tests\MySQL Tests\Program.cs:line 13

Nachricht means message, quelle means error, stapelüberwachung means .. i don´t know

Any ideas how to fix this?

Greetings,
Murf

Comment: when you use ``*`` like a target, in this line ``list.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader[target]))`` it's try to get  ``dataReader["*"]``, and you don't have a column name ``*``, it's normal that's thrown an exception. add another parameter ``string start``("*"); and use it in the query like : ``!string.IsnullOrEmpt(start)?start : target ...``

Comment: Hi @Murf you are adding to your list but never saving. Add this line after list.add, list.SaveChanges(). Hence the index out of range exception

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Also, `this.CloseConnection()` is [almost always a mistake.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query/398790#398790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing * it seems that you want multiple columns instead of just the first one.

```
public List<string> SelectListRow(string target, string table,string idef, int id)
    {
        string query = "SELECT " + target + " FROM " + table + " where "+ idef + " = " +id;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        if (this.OpenConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++) {
                {
                    list.Add(dataReader.GetString(i));
                }
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
            return list;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

That will get you the values that you require.
One additional thing I noticed is that if there is an exception that the connection data reader arent cleaned up. You can fix this by using try block with a finally clause or wrapping these in 'using' blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using the data reader with the column name use
dataReader.GetString(0) which would give the first column.

```
public List<string> SelectListRow(string target, string table,string idef, int id)
    {
        string query = "SELECT " + target + " FROM " + table + " where "+ idef + " = " +id;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        if (this.OpenConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {

                list.Add(dataReader.GetString(0));
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
            return list;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: this gave me just the first entry.
I expect  " 3, Test GmbH, hallo, Müller Manfred" and i just got "3"